# Is there a character limit for a Server-Event Streaming?

Tags: node.js, streaming, http-streaming, eventsource

I'm working on a streaming server-event (EventSource), and I need to send really big JSONs through it. Is there a character limit? Will the message be trimmed or not sent if the message is too long? I couldn't find anything related on the web.

Comment: How big are the JSONs?

Comment: I would say they could easily get up to 8000 chars.